# Local Data Cache - How do I refresh the local db when I add fields to remote db?

Tags: c#-3.0, microsoft-sync-framework, syncservices

I'm using a Local Data Cache in an ASP.NET 3.5 environment. I made a change in my main database by adding a new field.

I double click on my .SYNC file in my project to startup the Local Data Cache wizard again. The wizard starts and I click OK with the hopes that it'll re-query my database and add the new field to the local database file.

Instead, I get an error saying "Synchronizing the databae failed with the message: Unable to enumerate changes at the DbServerSyncProvider..."

The only way I know to get things working again is to delete the .SYNC file along with the local database and start it from scratch.

There's got to be an easier way... anyone know it?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get it to work in the sync designer, if you deselect the table giving you the problem and then sync and then add it back, it will rebuild the local cache file and all will be well.

Another way is to change the sync to to Entire table each time, sync and then change it back.